# compatibility of kepler plugins with indigo

Tags: plugins, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-indigo

I am using eclipse indigo. And I have kepler version's plugins which are needed for my project. Can I just copy-paste them in the plugins folder of eclipse indigo which I am currently using now?

Answer (score 1):

In general, No, you can't use plugins from newer versions of Eclipse in an older release. Some plugins might work but the combination will not have been tested.